# Ajax Cross Domain Library

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to program something that need to use "Cross Domain Ajax". But the jQuery is far too big for me and it has high coulping for me to take apart. But I really don't want to rewrite the whole Library.

I find one "www.ajax-cross-domain.com". However it writes in Perl acting as CGI, which is not really ideal.

Is there any other libraries with "Cross Domain Ajax" function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a server-side script that does the cross-domain potion for you and your JavaScript can just call it on the same server.

Comment: Nah ja, but it was not so convenient for the one who uses my service.